# Troubles with clipboard in Python

Tags: python, windows, clipboard

I'm learning Python right now and I want to write some script that will helps me with work. The idea is: `while True:` read some string from clipboard, modify it then return it into the clipboard then `sleep`. So I can paste modified data to anywhere.

Now I'm stuck in using `win32clipboard` module. I'm using this code:

```
import win32clipboard

def openClipboard():
    win32clipboard.OpenClipboard()

def closeClipboard():
    try:
        win32clipboard.CloseClipboard()
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

def getClipboardData():
    if win32clipboard.IsClipboardFormatAvailable(win32clipboard.CF_TEXT):
        return win32clipboard.GetClipboardData()
    else:
        return None

def setClipboardData(data):
    win32clipboard.EmptyClipboard()
    win32clipboard.SetClipboardData(win32clipboard.CF_TEXT, data)

#assume that I copied '000'

openClipboard()
data = getClipboardData()
print(data) //output: 000, so it's ok
closeClipboard()

openClipboard()
win32clipboard.EmptyClipboard()
setClipboardData(data + '123')
closeClipboard()

openClipboard()
data = getClipboardData()
print(data) //output: 0 0 0 1 2 3, but wtf? o_0
closeClipboard()
```

I can't understand why there are spaces in the second output?

Comment: I am not sure but you probably have problems whit formatting input.
Try insted whit SetClipboardText and play whit input format options.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**ralu**, thanks. I've got it at the same time I've got your answer. I should've use `win32clipboard.SetClipboardText(data)` instead of `win32clipboard.SetClipboardData(win32clipboard.CF_TEXT, data)`.

Comment: If there is a need to read or write Unicode then use `win32clipboard.SetClipboardData(win32clipboard.CF_UNICODETEXT, data)` and `win32clipboard.GetClipboardData(win32clipboard.CF_UNICODETEXT)`.

Comment: I'm just curious: why win32clipboard.SetClipboardData(win32clipboard.CF_TEXT, data) doesn't work? What's the logic behind?