# Python using win32api, simulate mouse movements and copy/paste into diskfile

Tags: python, winapi

Hello all…I am using win32api. The use is to move mouse on computer screen, highlight an area, copy the content, and send the contents to an MS Excel spreadsheet.

Here is the code:

```
import xlwt
import win32api
import win32con 
import win32clipboard
import time

x,y = win32api.GetCursorPos()
win32api.SetCursorPos((36, 311))

# choose the contents, highlight area from 36,311 to 66,400
win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN,x,y,0,0) 
time.sleep(0.05)
win32api.SetCursorPos((66, 400))
win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP,x,y,0,0)

# copy the contents
time.sleep(0.05)
win32clipboard.OpenClipboard()
win32clipboard.EmptyClipboard
aaa = win32clipboard.SetClipboardData
win32clipboard.CloseClipboard()

# write the contents into speadsheet
book = xlwt.Workbook(encoding='utf-8', style_compression = 0)
sheet = book.add_sheet('SheetOK', cell_overwrite_ok = True)
sheet.write (1, 1, aaa)
book.save("C:\\paste_write.xls")
```

it’s not working and returning an error “Exception: Unexpected data type ”. It looks like the copy&paste part doesn’t work out.

Can you help me? Thanks.

**error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\simulate mouse click.py", line 27, in <module>
    sheet.write (0, 0, aaa)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\xlwt\Worksheet.py", line 1030, in write
    self.row(r).write(c, label, style)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\xlwt\Row.py", line 259, in write
    raise Exception("Unexpected data type %r" % type(label))
Exception: Unexpected data type <type 'builtin_function_or_method'>
```

Comment: Please paste the full error messages when asking questions.

Comment: thanks Peter Gibson for reply. error added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message shows you the line of code where it fails:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\simulate mouse click.py", line 27, in <module>
    sheet.write (0, 0, aaa)
  ^^^ THIS YOUR FUNCTION CALL THAT FAILED

  File "C:\Python27\lib\xlwt\Worksheet.py", line 1030, in write
    self.row(r).write(c, label, style)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\xlwt\Row.py", line 259, in write
    raise Exception("Unexpected data type %r" % type(label))
  ^^^ THIS IS WHERE IT ACTUALLY FAILED IN THE LIBRARY

Exception: Unexpected data type <type 'builtin_function_or_method'>
```

The error message is telling you that something received an "Unexpected data type" which was of type 'builtin_function_or_method'. So the call to `sheet.write` happens, but it objects to the data that you're passing in.

If you look back to what's in the value of `aaa`:

```
aaa = win32clipboard.SetClipboardData
```

Ahh - what you meant to do here is evaluate the function, but you've left off the parenthesis `(` & `)`. So what has happened is that `aaa` has been assigned the function *itself*. To call the function, look at this answer for details [Troubles with clipboard in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9119899/66349)

You've also left of the parenthesis from the function on the line above that.

```
win32clipboard.EmptyClipboard
```

Instead try the following:

```
win32clipboard.EmptyClipboard()
win32clipboard.SetClipboardText("test data")
...
aaa = win32clipboard.GetClipboardText()
```

---

There seems to be a second problem here though, that you have to pass data to `SetClipbardData` - it doesn't trigger a *copy* action on the current selected text. You might need to use a different API for that.

Comment: Mr. Peter Gibson, thanks for the very detailed explanation. it's impressive.

Comment: for such task (copy an screen area then write the copied into a file), what API would you recommend?

Comment: @MarkK it seems that you want to remote control a program. you send some mousemovement and clicks. so also send the command that normally advises the program to copy the selection (mostly strg-c) so that the controlled program itself fills the clipboard

Comment: @vlad_tepesch, yes I want to build kind of automation because the work requires duplicated copy&paste from 1 screen to Excel file, and i am trying to see if Python can do the job.