# copying and pasting Unicode characters (specifically hebrew) from clipboard using win32clipboard

Tags: python, unicode

I have been running into some troubles with UTF8 encoding/decoding.
What i want to do is to copy a text from the windows clipboard, change it and paste the result.

To do so, I created a dictionary with Hebrew letters as keys and the corresponding new letters i want to assign.

here is an example of the code I use:

```
# !/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

hebToEng = {u"א":"t", u"ב":"c", u"ג":"d"}

win32clipboard.OpenClipboard()
data = win32clipboard.GetClipboardData().encode('utf-8')
win32clipboard.CloseClipboard()
print data
for i in range(0, len(data)):
    data[i] = hebToEng[data[i]]
print data
```

so when copying `"אבג"` i should have `"dct"` printed.

I have a few problems with the above code:

1.when i get the data from the clipboard and print it to see what got extracted, all is get `"???"`.

2.python does not allow me to access the dictionary with hebrew characters as keys, if I try to run the following code snippet:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

hebToEng = {u"א":"t", u"ב":"c", u"ג":"d"}

data = u"אאבג"
for i in range(0,len(data)):
    data[i] = hebToEng[data[i]]
print data
```

I get "`TypeError: 'unicode' object does not support item assignment`.

I would appreciate the input on how to solving these problems.
Thanks.

Comment: For the latter one - strings (including unicode) are immutable, use a new variable to append the chars as you loop through them.

Comment: Wow, you are right and i totally forgot that, Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it! after lots of searching i found this post:
[Troubles with clipboard in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9119899/troubles-with-clipboard-in-python)

the solution is as simple as editing the copying function to:

```
win32clipboard.GetClipboardData( win32clipboard.CF_UNICODETEXT)
```

This solves the problem it ever occurs to anyone.